# Guard packadd to not load an optional non-existent package

Tags: vimscript, packages

I have an "optional" plugin that depends on python (`pack/habamax/opt/myplugin`)

in my settings I have the following:

```
if has('python') || has('python3')
    do some setup
    packadd myplugin
endif
```

This thing fails if there is no myplugin though.

Is there a way I can add to an if statement to check if myplugin exists? `if packexists('myplugin')`?

I can probably have a `try catch` to suppress errors but the thing is that there might be `elseif`:

```
" if there is package myplugin and all dependencies
if has('python') || has('python3')
    do some setup
    packadd myplugin
else
"use another plugin without dependencies
    do some setup
    packadd anotherplugin
endif
```

@Matt,

[image]

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the help.

I end up using `silent! packadd ...`:

```
" try to load myplugin first
if has('python') || has('python3')
    do some setup
    silent! packadd myplugin
endif

"use another plugin without dependencies
if !exists("g:myplugin_loaded")
    do some setup
    packadd anotherplugin
endif
```

Comment: If no one comes up with a proper solution, you can easily workaround the `else` requirement by setting a flag if `packadd` is successful, and loading your other plugin in an `if` block that checks if the flag is set.

Comment: As it's an "optional" plugin, what do you mean by "exists": exists in path or was already loaded?

Comment: @Matt exists in path, not loaded. I want to load it if dependencies are satisfied

Comment: @Rich so `try catch` in that case?

Comment: @MaximKim Yep. Actually, thinking about it, most plugins set a `loaded` flag themselves, so you could just use that. (See my comment on statox's answer)

Comment: `packadd` does not throw an exception. So you have to `packadd` and then additionally check if there's `loaded_myplugin` flag, or `exists('smth')`, or whatever else.

Comment: @Matt Huh, I thought this question was *about* working around an exception. Oh well!

Comment: @Matt, I have updated question with a screenshot of an error if I try to packadd nonexistent package

Comment: Sorry, that was my fault. Basically, you have to merge both answers you were already given: first, do `silent! packadd myplugin`, and then check if `exists('something')` or not.

Comment: @Matt, np, I have already done it my config. Works well! Thx a lot!

Comment: `:echo  len(glob('/home/user/.vim/pack/*/{opt,start}/plugin',0,1)) > 0`?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt indeed, I forgot about globbing, `echo len(glob(fnamemodify($MYVIMRC, ":h").'/pack/mypack/*/LeaderF',0,1)) > 0
` could also be used

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt You should really loop over all the locations in `'packpath'` to be robust, no?

Comment: @Matt Indeed; I'm not sure how or why this error is being thrown... it happens with `vim -u NONE` though

Comment: @Rich if the plugin hasn't been loaded yet, it is not available in the packpath. Might use `globpath()` and glob over the `runtimepath`.

Comment: @MaximKim well, where do you know `mypack` from?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt it is name of the pack where I supposedly install my packages (not from package manager like minpac). To be frank it is called `habamax` in my `pack/` folder.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I mean you should to glob for the package in all the locations in `'packpath'` (because that's where `:packadd` searches), not just in hardcoded `/home/user/.vim/pack`.

Comment: @Rich yes but the packpath default path comes from `runtimepath` and I believe it always appends a `pack` to any of the paths there. but yes, grepping packpath might also be needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just

```
silent! packadd <plugin>
```

Comment: Thx, this really suppress the error. So with that I can also check if package has been really loaded with `g:loaded...` variables

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`:h exists()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#exists%28%29) to test if a variable, a command or a function provided by the plugin is defined. If it is defined then it means the plugin is available:

```
exists({expr})  The result is a Number, which is |TRUE| if {expr} is
        defined, zero otherwise.

        The {expr} argument is a string, which contains one of these:
            &option-name    Vim option (only checks if it exists,
                    not if it really works)
            [...]
            *funcname   built-in function (see |functions|)
                    or user defined function (see
                    |user-functions|). Also works for a
                    variable that is a Funcref.
            [...]
            :cmdname    Ex command: built-in command, user
                    command or command modifier |:command|.
                    Returns:
                    1  for match with start of a command
                    2  full match with a command
                    3  matches several user commands
                    To check for a supported command
                    always check the return value to be 2.
```

So the idea is to check for something defined by the plugin. For example if you want to test that GitGutter is installed you can check for the `g:loaded_gitgutter` variable it defines like this:

```
if (exists('g:loaded_gitgutter'))
    nnoremap <C-L> :nohlsearch\|GitGutter<CR><C-L>
endif
```

Note that most of the plugins should defined a variable of the form `g:loaded_pluginname` as @Rich pointed out in the comments.

Comment: Command doesn't exist -- myplugin is in opt and not loaded unless I try to `packadd` it. Or am I missing something?

Comment: `g:loaded_gitgutter` is probably a less brittle thing to check. Most plugins have a similar variable, as it's recommended in the "how to write a plugin" docs.

Comment: @MaximKim The idea is to grab something defined by your plugin, so maybe it has a `g:loaded_XXX` variable or something like this, if you can share the name of the plugin we can check that. @ Rich definitely a better way to do it indeed.

Comment: @statox that is LeaderF plugin

Comment: @Rich do all g variables exist even if I didn't add a package from opt with `packadd`?

Comment: For LeaderF, it's [`g:leaderf_loaded`](https://github.com/Yggdroot/LeaderF/blob/master/plugin/leaderf.vim#L10)

Comment: @MaximKim Not sure if I'm understanding your question right, but the global `loaded` variable will be set whenever the plugin is loaded. See NOT LOADING under `:help use-cpo-save` for the where setting up this variable is recommended in the docs.

Comment: @Rich, yes I have found it and together with `silent! packadd` it works as I need it

Comment: @Rich the issue is when there is no plugin in `pack/.../opt/` directory. Then barebone packadd throws an error. I wanted to check if plugin exists first and then to load it. But I can also use `silent!` to try to load plugin first and then to check `g:leaderf_loaded`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a `try`/`catch` block and a local variable to control whether you managed to load it successfully.

```
let has_myplugin = 0
" if there is package myplugin and all dependencies
if has('python') || has('python3')
    do some setup
    try
        packadd myplugin
        let has_myplugin = 1
    catch /^Vim\%((\a\+)\)\=:E919:/
        " Directory not found in packpath.
        " Fallback to the ! has_myplugin case.
    endtry
endif

if ! has_myplugin
    " use another plugin without dependencies
    do some setup
    packadd anotherplugin
endif
```

Also consider that you might want to use `packadd!` if you're doing it from your `vimrc` file. From `:help :packadd`:

> When the optional `!` is added no plugin files or ftdetect scripts are loaded, only the matching  directories are added to `runtimepath`.  This is    useful in your `.vimrc`.  The plugins will then be loaded during initialization, see `load-plugins`.

(See also: `:help :packloadall`.)

Comment: Thx, try catch came first to my mind but I wasn't sure about it

Comment: Eek, a naked `catch`! You might want to catch command not found or some specific error

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Yeah good point! Fixed now. Possibly too specific, but maybe that's good? Would probably need to test that it works as expected.

Comment: Nice! (Filler text)